# Restricting multi category to set number according to select package

Tags: html, wordpress, templates

I am helping a client build a wordpress directory. The theme in use is ListingPro. My client is wanting to restrict the number of categories allowed according to the package selected.

for example: 
Gold package - No. of catergories allowed: 5
Platinum package - No. of catergories allowed: 10

At the moment, the theme allows for all categories to be selected.

I dont have the coding knowledge to make this happen. I am looking for advice, help or a direction I should look at for help.

Comment: You would benefit more from asking the theme creators. You might get an answer here but you will likely get a more accurate answer from the people who coded it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure without digging into this plugin's code, but I'd start by looking through and seeing where and how it stores the information of listings.

Basically, you're looking to intercept the function that posts a listing, and you'll want to do a get_posts (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) request that sees how many posts attributed to the logged in user has made with any given category.